# Why MEMORY is increasing when using PHCachingImageManager

Tags: ios, objective-c

[Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html)

I'm learning how to write a customized imagePicker, and I found this example which uses caching in grid view.

But in the grid view, when I continuously swipe up and down I found that memory in increasing, although I have totally reach the start position and the end position for many times.

I'm sure the issue is caused in function `updateCachedAssets`, but I don't know what causes the issue. Why memory in increasing without leaking and retain cycle???

So, anyone can help me.